# JMXtrans not creating rrd's of kafka metrics for ganglia

Tags: apache-kafka, ganglia, jmxtrans

I am trying to monitor a kafka broker using jmxtrans and ganglia. However with the below json, no rrd's being created.

```
{
"servers": [
    {
        "port": "9999",
        "host": "localhost",
        "queries": [
            {
                "outputWriters": [
                    {
                        "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.GangliaWriter",
                        "settings": {
                            "groupName": "kafka topic stats",
                            "port": 8649,
                            "host": "localhost",
            "typeNames":[
                "name"
            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "obj": "\"kafka.server\":type=\"BrokerTopicMetrics\",name=\"*\"",
                "resultAlias": "Kafka",
                "attr": [
                    "Count",
                    "OneMinuteRate"
                ]
            },
            {
                "outputWriters": [
                    {
                        "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.GangliaWriter",
                        "settings": {
                            "groupName": "kafka server request",
                            "port": 8649,
                            "host": "localhost"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "obj": "\"kafka.network\":type=\"RequestMetrics\",name=\"Produce-RequestsPerSec\"",
                "resultAlias": "produce",
                "attr": [
                    "Count",
                    "OneMinuteRate"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "numQueryThreads": 2
    }
]
}
```

The log printed in jmxtrans.log is

`[01 Sep 2015 11:53:28] [SIGTERM handler] 4030449 DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.JmxTransformer:463) - Stopped writer: GangliaWriter for query: Query [obj="kafka.network":type="RequestMetrics",name="Produce-RequestsPerSec", resultAlias=produce, attr=[Count, OneMinuteRate]]
[01 Sep 2015 11:54:33] [main] 0      DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.JmxTransformer:223) - Loaded file: /usr/share/jmxtrans/kafka-test.json
[01 Sep 2015 11:54:33] [main] 5      DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.JmxTransformer:297) - Scheduled job: localhost:9999-1441088673052 for server: Server [host=localhost, port=9999, url=null, cronExpression=null, numQueryThreads=2]
[01 Sep 2015 11:54:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-1] 9      DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob:31) - +++++ Started server job: Server [host=localhost, port=9999, url=null, cronExpression=null, numQueryThreads=2]
[01 Sep 2015 11:54:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-1] 38     DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.util.JmxUtils:95) - ----- Creating 2 query threads
[01 Sep 2015 11:54:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-1] 43     DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob:50) - +++++ Finished server job: Server [host=localhost, port=9999, url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi, cronExpression=null, numQueryThreads=2]
[01 Sep 2015 11:55:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-2] 60006  DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob:31) - +++++ Started server job: Server [host=localhost, port=9999, url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi, cronExpression=null, numQueryThreads=2]
[01 Sep 2015 11:55:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-2] 60008  DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.util.JmxUtils:95) - ----- Creating 2 query threads
[01 Sep 2015 11:55:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-2] 60014  DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob:50) - +++++ Finished server job: Server [host=localhost, port=9999, url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi, cronExpression=null, numQueryThreads=2]
[01 Sep 2015 11:56:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-3] 120006 DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob:31) - +++++ Started server job: Server [host=localhost, port=9999, url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi, cronExpression=null, numQueryThreads=2]
[01 Sep 2015 11:56:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-3] 120008 DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.util.JmxUtils:95) - ----- Creating 2 query threads
[01 Sep 2015 11:56:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-3] 120014 DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob:50) - +++++ Finished server job: Server [host=localhost, port=9999, url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi, cronExpression=null, numQueryThreads=2]
[01 Sep 2015 11:57:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-4] 180006 DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob:31) - +++++ Started server job: Server [host=localhost, port=9999, url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi, cronExpression=null, numQueryThreads=2]
[01 Sep 2015 11:57:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-4] 180009 DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.util.JmxUtils:95) - ----- Creating 2 query threads
[01 Sep 2015 11:57:33] [ServerScheduler_Worker-4] 180014 DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.jobs.ServerJob:50) - +++++ Finished server job: Server [host=localhost, port=9999, url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi, cronExpression=null, numQueryThreads=2]`

However I tried to get normal java memory information instead of the kafka metrices, the rrd's are generated.
Please suggest if I am making any config mistake or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your log file, no metrics send to gmond. You have error in json file. For correct work replace:

`"obj": "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=*",` 
and

`"obj": "kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=Produce-RequestsPerSec",` restart jmxtrans daemon and you should see in jmxtrans log file same as:

`[12 Sep 2015 01:25:11] [pool-22-thread-1] 630550 DEBUG (com.googlecode.jmxtrans.util.JmxUtils:195) - Executing queryName: kafka.server:name=BytesInPerSec,type=BrokerTopicMetrics from query: Query [obj=kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=*, resultAlias=Kafka, attr=[Count, OneMinuteRate]]`